# Text runs out when zoom level set to 25%

Tags: html, css

When i zoom-in my website to 25%, the text runs out oddly. How can i fix this? Pls have a look at the below link, where you can see the result of a mock-up. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/schenker76/YqX9r/embedded/result/

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you're expecting to occur and what you feel is happening.

Answer (score 1):

First, this problem only occurs in Chrome, and so is probably resulting mainly from rounding errors (Chrome tends to truncate decimals in element positions).  Firefox is only showing nigh-insignificant variations in text wrapping, and IE is keeping the text exactly to scale with the rest of the document.

The simplest solution is probably to stop absolute-positioning everything, if that can work with your design.  If the text were allowed to follow the normal flow, then it would look OK in every browser, though Chrome would still do some minor jumping around like you see in Firefox (and the "wel_txt" element might get very large, relatively speaking, due to the text not shrinking fast enough).

To clear up the problem with fewer design adjustments, you could position the "wel_hdr" element using `top` instead of `bottom`, and... perhaps give "wel_txt" `overflow: auto` so that it gets a scrollbar rather than hiding the text completely.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width from `#wel_txt` in % than in pixels, will fix the problem.

```
#wel_txt {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 92px;
    top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps.